# Debugger not stoping at breakpoint in RxJava for Android

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio, rx-java, rx-android

The `Log.d(...)` expression in the `catch(...)` block below gets executed (I can see the log output in Android Studio), but the debugger won't stop at the breakpoint set at that very same line. Why is that? The debugger stops at other breakpoints.

```
Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<MobileBankIdSessionResponse.MobileBankIdSession>() {
       @Override
       public void call(final Subscriber<? super MobileBankIdSessionResponse.MobileBankIdSession> subscriber) {
           Schedulers.newThread().createWorker().schedule(new Action0() {
               @Override
               public void call() {
                   try {
                       MobileBankIdSessionResponse r = User.getMobileBankIdSession(reference, nationalIdentity).toBlocking().first();
                       String progressCode = r.getResponse().progress.progressCode;
                       if (StringUtils.equals(progressCode, "COMPLETE")) {
                           subscriber.onNext(r.getResponse());
                           subscriber.onCompleted();
                       } else if (StringUtils.equals(progressCode, "USER_SIGN")
                               || StringUtils.equals(progressCode, "OUTSTANDING_TRANSACTION")) {
                           Schedulers.newThread().createWorker().schedule(this, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                       } else if (StringUtils.equals(progressCode, "NO_CLIENT")) {
                           subscriber.onError(new Throwable("Fel vid signering"));
                       }
                   } catch (Exception e) {
                       Log.d("AtError", "here");
                       subscriber.onError(e);
                   }
               }
           });
       }
   }).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(new Observer<MobileBankIdSessionResponse.MobileBankIdSession>() {
       @Override
       public void onCompleted() {}

       @Override
       public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
           mUserLoggedInOutSubject.onNext(Pair.create(throwable.getMessage(), LoginStates.ERROR));
       }

       @Override
       public void onNext(MobileBankIdSessionResponse.MobileBankIdSession mobileBankIdSession) {
           setSession(mobileBankIdSession.session, nationalIdentity);
       }
   });
```

Comment: Rebuild Project and put a breakpoint on both lines : `Log.d(...)` and  `subscriber.onError(e)` and try. It happens sometimes. I have faced this issue, not sure about the reason behind it.

Comment: Thank you @MonishKamble, but that didn't solve it.

Comment: I'm facing the same thing now.  Is there any new information on this?

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who came here for answer, It is possible you have not called `.subscribe(e ->{});` on the Single ,Flowable etc Object you are using.